# GeoServer PostGIS Store Connection problem - Cannot see database

Tags: postgis, geoserver

GeoServer => 2.20.1 (Jetty)

PostgreSQL => "PostgreSQL 13.3, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit"

PostGIS => "POSTGIS=""3.1.2 3.1.2"" [EXTENSION] PGSQL=""130"" GEOS=""3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.1"" SFCGAL=""1.3.8"" PROJ=""7.1.1"" LIBXML=""2.9.9"" LIBJSON=""0.12"" LIBPROTOBUF=""1.2.1"" WAGYU=""0.5.0 (Internal)"" TOPOLOGY"

I have a localhost PostgreSQL database called dfdb which I can access using qGIS and pgAdmin 4 (next image):

[image: pgAdmin Accessing dfdb database on localhost]

GeoServer Store PostGIS parameters.

[image]

When I try to create this Store in GeoServer (localhost database dfdb) I get the following error:

> Error creating data store, check the parameters. Error message: Unable to obtain connection: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: database "dfdb" does not exist)

Can anyone help me work out what is going on?

I had a look at other solutions to connection issues but I couldn't work out if they applied in my case.

Turning on developer logging I get (seubset):

```
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to obtain connection: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: database "dfdb" does not exist)

    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.createConnection(JDBCDataStore.java:2147)

    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.createTypeNames(JDBCDataStore.java:934)

    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getTypeNames(ContentDataStore.java:261)

    at org.vfny.geoserver.util.DataStoreUtils.getDataAccess(DataStoreUtils.java:73)

    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getDataStore(ResourcePool.java:626)

    ... 146 more

Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: database "dfdb" does not exist)

    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)

    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)

    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)

    at org.geotools.data.jdbc.datasource.AbstractManageableDataSource.getConnection(AbstractManageableDataSource.java:42)

    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.createConnection(JDBCDataStore.java:2131)

    ... 150 more

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "dfdb" does not exist

    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)

    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2665)

    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.<init>(QueryExecutorImpl.java:147)

    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:273)

    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)

    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)

    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)

    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)

    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)

    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)

    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)

    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)

    ... 154 more
```

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: what settings did you use in GeoServer? are they exactly the same as in PGAdmin?

Comment: I have added another image showing the Store database connection properties to my original request.

Comment: I still have no solution. I suspect the issue is less to do with GeoServer but more to do with the database driver not being able to connect to non-default databases.

Comment: How geoserver and postgresql is running? Docker etc?

Comment: PostgreSQL is running as a Windows Service. GeoServer is running under the standard GeoServer Jetty Windows download on the same machine.